# Prove that normal vector to the surface does not depend on parameterization

Tags: calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

A given surface can be parameterize in many different ways. How to prove that  a change in parameters, given a smooth, invertible map between the two parameter domains, does not change a normal vector to the surface? I have the intuition about it, but trying so hard I still can`t prove it strictly.

**EDIT:** I mean that if we have equivalent parametrizations, that comprize the positive orientation of the surface, then a unit normal vector does not change.

Comment: They will not be the same : $\vec{N_2}=k\vec{N_1}$ and this value of $k$ (which might even be $<0$) is interesting...

Comment: The unit normal vector is a property of the surface itself, up to orientation. If we agree on orientation, the grid you place on it doesn't change it in any way.

Comment: Could you say a little what you have tried ? It may help for advices or solutions we can provide...

Comment: @DavidP I beg your pardon, but we are all aware of that.I think that niar_q wants to do a calculation in order to find back this property.

Comment: @JeanMarie You cannot have my pardon

Comment: In surface theory normal vector is intrinsic, depending only on first fundamental form derivable.

Comment: @Narasimhan Yes, I agree, but what I wanted to stress by writing $$\vec{N_2}=k\vec{N_1}$$ is the important fact that the change of parameterization is reflected in coefficient $k$ which is a ratio of infinitesimal areas induced by the first and the second parameterizations, and this is important to understand for somebody who enters into this field. Taking the **unit** normal suppress this information. I have seen so many students that had no idea that a cross product is in relationship with (oriented) areas...That's all what I wanted to say, and I do not want to enter into any conflict...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you cannot prove it because it's false.

Consider the usual parameterization of the sphere:

$$
(u, v) \mapsto (\cos u \cos v, \sin u \cos v, \sin v)
$$
where $- \pi/2 \le v \le \pi/2$.

Now compose it with the map $(u, v) \mapsto (u, -v)$, to get

$$
(u, v) \mapsto (\cos u \cos v, \sin u \cos v, -\sin v)
$$

The resulting parameterizations produce opposite normal vectors; the normals point inward in the one, and outward in the other.

To get the result you want, you need the change-of-variables formula to be a smooth invertible map between the domains, and the Jacobian determinant must be positive at each point.

Answer (score 0):

In surface theory normal vector is intrinsic depending only on first fundamental form and its dependants $(H^2 = E G -F^2 , L N - M^2)$.

Referring to Weingarten relations and second fundamental form,

$$ H N_1 \times N_2 = (LN - M^2).  $$ The latter is invariant by Gauss theorem.( unsubscripted N is of second fundamental form), Normal vector to surface is parametrization-free.